# how can operate network printer through web page?

Tags: vbscript, printing

i have an intranet web page that need to send text to a network label printer to print it.
how can i do that?

Comment: How on earth is this a SuperUser question, close voters?

Answer (score 2):

This is really not something you should be doing on the client side. Write a server-side script to send the appropriate data to the printer.

Comment: so how do you do it in server-side script?